# HTML Dropdown and Textbox with custom border different widths

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown box and a text box.

I searched this site but could not find the answer for my problem.

I have the following styles applied to each, but the dropdown is significantly shorter than the textbox due to the custom border.

```
border: 1px solid #E05206;
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
font-size: 1.2em;
padding: 0 5px;
width: 335px;
```

Does anyone know of a fix for this for all browsers, each browser has a different length.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Worked it out, is the way padding is added to the dropdown, the padding increases the overall width of the textbox, but does not do the same to the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out, is the way padding is added to the dropdown, the padding increases the overall width of the textbox, but does not do the same to the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Add div with fixed width put your control inside it and change width in your css to 100%

that should resolve your problem.

Comment: That does not solve the issue. This would work if there was no padding on the textbox

Comment: are you sure that this doesnt works, just change css width for text box to 100%

Comment: I am sure, it is the padding that is causing me the issue, so the textbox will be 100% plus the padding, and the dropdown will just be 100%